# How to Sum two Different tax values amount individually

Tags: sql

I've been trying to sum two different tax values amount from one table and my table is like below

```
Sales table:    
Customer_id    Tax_percent   Tax_amount
  100            5%            2.50
  100            14.5%         6.75
  101            5%            1.25
  102            5%            2.00
  101            14.5%         9.50
```

My output will be like:

```
total 5% amount is 5.75 

total 14.5% amount is 16.25
```

---

Please help.

Comment: look up `sum` and `group by`

Comment: SELECT Tax_percent   , SUM(Tax_amount) FROM Sales
Group By Tax_percent

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: "Please help" obviously means "please write the query for me" here. I suggest you rather read your book or tutorial and learn. This is a very basic query as you can see from the answers, and with some reading you should have been able to write it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Use SUM and GROUP By functions :

```
 SELECT Tax_percent , SUM(Tax_amount)
 FROM your_table
 GROUP BY Tax_percent
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @Salestable table(Customer_id int,   Tax_percent numeric(5,2),  Tax_amount numeric(5,2))
insert into @Salestable values(  100   ,         5       ,     2.50)
insert into @Salestable values(  100   ,         14.5    ,     6.75)
insert into @Salestable values(  101   ,         5       ,     1.25)
insert into @Salestable values(  102   ,         5       ,     2.00)
insert into @Salestable values(  101   ,         14.5    ,     9.50)

select Tax_percent,sum(Tax_amount) from @Salestable group by Tax_percent
```